# Complete command from history in ipython

Tags: ipython

For reasons outside of my control I'm stuck using python 2.6.6 and IPython 0.10.2. I also normally use the `tcsh` shell, and have gotten quite used to completing a command from the history using `<A-p>` (i.e. pressing the `ALT` key and `p`). However, this doesn't work in IPython. I know I can press `<C-r>` and then start typing a command, but what inevitably is happening is that I start a command, press `<A-p>`, get a colon indicating some weird state, then exit out of that state, delete my command, press `<C-r>` then search for my command. It's getting rather irritating. Is there any way to make `<A-p>` complete my already started command by relying on the history?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ouch, this is an old version of IPython, Python (and pip). The bad news is I don't have much experience with such an old version of IPython, the good new is; it was way simpler at that time.

Most of the shortcut and feature are provided using readline, and the [python bindings of stdlib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html). Meaning that most likely what you are trying to configure is readline itself and not only IPython; so you can  find more information on that outside of IPython !

The secret is to `grep` in the source-code for `parse_and_bind`, then you'll find [the following example configuration](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/0.10.2/IPython/Extensions/ipy_defaults.py), leading me to change the `~/.ipython/ipy_user_conf.py` to be like so at around line 99 (all indented an extra 4 space to be in the `main()` function):

```
import readline
readline.parse_and_bind('set completion-query-items 1000')
readline.parse_and_bind('set page-completions no')
rlopts = """\
tab: complete
"\C-l": possible-completions
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
"\C-o": tab-insert
"\M-i": "    "
"\M-o": "\d\d\d\d"
"\M-I": "\d\d\d\d"
"\C-r": reverse-search-history
"\C-s": forward-search-history
"\C-p": history-search-backward
"\C-n": history-search-forward
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"\C-k": kill-line
"\C-u": unix-line-discard"""

for cmd in rlopts.split('\n'):
    readline.parse_and_bind(cmd)
```

The repetition of commands make me think that what `\C`,`\M` or `[e` mean  might be system dependant. I would bet on `\C` being Control, and `\M` being Meta (Alt, Opt), but at least one of these line did the trick for me (and also now `tab` allows to complete). See also `man readline` for the list of commands you can bind to what, and enjoy! Hoping you can upgrade to Python 3 and IPython 6 at some point.

[Edit]

See Eric Carlsen second comment under this answer for how it was resolved.

Comment: Thanks for the hints. It got me close, but I'm not sure how to surmount the last problem. I tried modifying the config file and changing the search to `"\M-p": history-search-backward` but that didn't work. I even printed it to make sure it was being called. However, I was able to change it to another, unused binding. I'm guessing that Alt-p is somehow captured or used somewhere else and I'm not able to override it. At the moment I'm actually finding it easier to modify `tcsh` to use C-p as a history search, so I'm just going to start using that everywhere instead.

Comment: I finally got it working, and the hint was right above in your code section. It turns out that `\C-` is what you need for Control-, but for Alt- you just need `\e`. And `ipython` respects your `.inputrc` readline bindings, so I added the following line to `.inputrc`:  `"\ep": history-search-backward` and `"\en": history-search-forward`